# Use of C1 in Arduino Mega schematics?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega

[image]

Please open [schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf) of Mega.

Can anyone explain why Cap C1 is used here? C1 is connected to RESET pin of ATmega2560. Also, ATmega16U2 pin 13 is connected to the RESET pin of ATmega2560. I am just not able to figure out the significance of this Capacitor in Auto RESET circuit.

Comment: The reset pin is connected to the reset button so C1 help debounce when you press the reset button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the ATmega datasheet, the reset is active low. My best guess is that the capacitor there serves to force a reset every time the power supply goes on.

On turn-on, the reset is pulled down to GND until the cap is fully charged.

Once the cap is charged, reset is pulled high through the resistor.

As pointed out by @JRE, the diode in parallel to the resistor serves as a path to quickly discharge the capacitor when the voltage drops.

Comment: Exactly right.  Would you care to address D3 while you are at it?  That would make your answer better.

Comment: @JRE: D3 is used to prevent any possible voltage spikes i think as RESET pin is active low.

Comment: @radiohead: and once cap is charged the RESET pin go high and now MCU is in a non- reset state?

Comment: Yes, once the cap is charged the RESET will be driven high through the pull up resistor.

Comment: D3 is used to pull down the reset pin as soon as the voltage drops.  With  out that, it would take longer for reset to be asserted when power fails - you would have to wait for C1 to discharge through the 10k resistor.

Comment: Oh good one, I did not see that! With your permission I'll edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: Go for it.  That was the idea.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the answers to both of you. :)

Comment: I think in fact D3 is used to prevent an initial voltage spike from taking the chip into high-voltage programming mode, which means it will then not work as expected. D3 clamps RESET to not exceed 5V.

Comment: @NickGammon  The D3 is there to provide a quick discharge path for the capacitor when the power is turned off.  Otherwise, the capacitor would have to discharge through the resistor, which would take longer.  (Same purpose as JRE described above.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev  Yes, I read that. But a 22 pF capacitor will discharge through 10k in 1 µs. Is anyone really going to care about that? I think my explanation about not going into high-voltage programming mode is more plausible.